# Read a file in clojure and display content both using command prompt

Tags: clojure, scripting, command-prompt

I have read the file as follows

```
(defn get-lines [file]
    (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
      (count (line-seq rdr))))

  (get-lines "D:/clojurefile/t2/ct.txt")
```

but it does not display the content
I want to print the data in my file on prompt!

Answer (score 1):

`(count (line-seq rdr))` returns the number of lines in the file. You should remove `count` to have the entire contents of the file printed:

```
(defn get-lines [file]
  (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
    (line-seq rdr)))

(println (get-lines "D:/clojurefile/t2/ct.txt"))
```

Edit: to print the contents of the file from command line (rather that in the REPL) you should use a print function - edited above. Also, if the file is not too large, it will be simpler to use the `slurp` function, which reads the file's contents in the memory at once, instead of `with-open`:

```
(println (slurp "D:/clojurefile/t2/ct.txt"))
```

Comment: I tried removing, it does not work!
also can you suggest me slurp function if possible?

Comment: Have you tried printing it? `(println (doall (line-seq rdr)))`. Since you mentioned seeing this from the command line i.e. stdout, you would need to print it out.

Comment: @jayk: does `(print (slurp "D:/clojurefile/t2/ct.txt"))` not work for you?